# Using DECLARE to create column numbers

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssms, multiple-columns, declare

When running a query I need column numbers to be applied to each row so that when I use the query to create a report in SSRS I can tell the report which data to put in which column.  Example:

```
  Case 1  |  Jane Doe       | Col 1 
  Case 1  |  John Doe       | Col 2
  Case 2  |  Sally Smith    | Col 1 (only name in case)
```

My current query uses:

```
DECLARE @NumOfCols int=2;
```

And then this to tell it how to separate the columns:

```
(row_number() over (partition by case_num order by child_first) + @NumOfCols - 1)% @NumOfCols + 1 as DisplayCol
```

The problem is, when I run the query, even if a result only has one name (so only one column is needed) my data is getting duplicated.  It seems like it is making it a mandatory column 1 and column 2 even if there is no data for a second column.  Like this:

```
  Case 1  |  Jane Doe     | Col 1 
  Case 1  |  John Doe     | Col 2
  Case 2  |  Sally Smith  | Col 1 (only name in case)
  Case 2  |  Sally Smith  | Col 2 (duplicating)
```

I hope this makes sense.  Any ideas on how to eliminate duplicating the data?

Comment: Can you post your full query please, I suspect there is some other issue as what you have shown will not cause any duplication. Also, not sure why you are subtracting 1, then getting a modulo, then adding 1 back.....it gives the same result as just the `row_number()` function.

Comment: My full query is too long to post in here, also I would have to tweak it a bit as I am not allowed to share per work policy.  But I can say I have broken down the query and it only duplicates in the end when I add that row number field.  I got the example for that while searching around, but I know if I don't use that I get an endless count of columns and not just the 1,2.

Comment: Are you joining any other tables? What conditions etc. I have simulated your data and run your code, I get no duplicates.

Comment: I am joining multiple tables and have multiple CTE's in my query.  When I do not include the row_number line in my select statement I do not have any duplicates but as soon as I add that line back into my select statement I get the duplicates.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that it is not the `row_number()` function that is causing the duplicates. Rather, in your query you are getting multiple rows that, without this line, are being resolved by a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` that is no longer being satisfied e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT Name` from a list with 5 different names over 15 rows you get 5 rows, the same with `row_number()...` will return 15 rows - John,1 is not the same as John,2.  Look for what else is happening. At the simplest level, put your query in a subquery and select everything plus your row_number function form that.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you're saying.  I will look into that further and see if that helps.  Thank you!